# Using SoundPool in a repeat loop, like CountDownTimer

Tags: android, repeat, countdowntimer, soundpool

I want to use SoundPool in a repeat loop, like CountDownTimer, to generate a beep every second, but whatever I do, the beep stops after 14 beeps. The CountDownTimer loop runs even 30 or more and executes other codes. I am reasonably new to Android. Can anyone help to sort this out?

I would like to run this at least for 15 minutes, preferably till the app closes. I have tried using other sounds(in my actual code) and narrowed down the problem to this.

````````````
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView cd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cd = findViewById(R.id.cd);

        new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                cd.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                playSoundPool(fourhundred);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                cd.setText("done!");
            }
        }.start();
    }


    private void playSoundPool(int soundID) {
        int MAX_STREAMS = 20;
        int REPEAT = 0;
        SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAMS, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, REPEAT);
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int soundId, int status) {
                int priority = 0;
                int repeat = 0;
                float rate = 1.f; 
                AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                float streamVolumeCurrent =
                        mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float streamVolumeMax =
                        mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;
                // Play it
                soundPool.play(soundId, volume, volume, priority, repeat, rate);
            }
        });
        soundPool.load(this, soundID, 1);
    }
}
```````````

I expect the beep to repeat 30 times and stop, but it stops after 14 beeps; at the same time text is updated 30 times and stops.

~~~~~~~~~~~
I could capture the RUN window messages during this behavior. Please see below, the messages for 13th and 14th beep[here the "numero" is just a dummy variable that starts from 72 and goes up]. I believe this would provide some more insight:
~~~~~~~~~~~
W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer 4, track 44100 Hz, output 48000 Hz
I/System.out: Numero: 84
I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer 4, track 44100 Hz, output 48000 Hz
I/System.out: Numero: 85
I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer 4, track 44100 Hz, output 48000 Hz
E/AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
E/SoundPool: Error creating AudioTrack
I/System.out: Numero: 86

~~~~~~~~~
The same message is repeated here onwards.
````````````

Comment: are you waiting for the beep to finish?

Comment: Yes! every beep is 0.5 sec, and the repeats are in 1 sec each.